# distribute many ultrasonic sensor in specific area

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am working on a project in which I have to use ultrasonic sensors HC-SR04.
I need to know how can determine the number of sensors that is separate in the circumference to coverage area (such as 40cm * 100cm)  ? And how can get the ideal location among each sensor in this area?
"the picture which I attach just to show what i need as example"
[example about what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zgab.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only 3 sensors, as in your example the location of S3 and S4 is okay, put only 1 more sensor in front location in the middle point of S3 & S4 ( opposite face ) .
I have exactly as this project, but i need to programs these 3 sensors with some algorithm to distribute them in a scientific forms
Good Luck